# About php and javascript function calling and transfer String variable

Tags: javascript, php

How can I let the $Categories_name or $cat to be a string?
As the result show that in "str_word_count($cat)

" is 3 when Test is "ABCD DEFD DDDD".

```
        <h2 id="CaCategories"></h2>
        <p id="CaTable"></p>

        <script>
            function CaFunction()
            {
                var text = document.getElementById("CategorySelect").value;
                        document.getElementById("CaCategories").innerHTML = "<?php echo 'This is " + text + "'; ?>";
                                    document.getElementById("CaTable").innerHTML = "<?php php_catable('This is " + text + "'); ?>";
            }
        </script>

        <!-- Generate Table by php and MySQL-->
        <?php
            function php_catable($Categories_name)
            {
                                 $cat = $Categories_name;
                                 echo "<br>$cat<br>";
                                 echo str_word_count($cat);
            }
        ?>
```

Comment: This is correct output as its counting the words (ABCD, DEFD, DDDD). Are you looking to for strlen($cat)? this will give you 14

Comment: Why it is wrong for the output because $cat = "This is ABCD DEFD DDDD", the answer I think is 5 strings in str_word_count($cat)...

But why 3 because when they transfer the "This is ABCD DEFD DDDD" to php function, my intention is count the "string", not the "object", they give me 3 that means "This"-->1, "is"-->2, and  "ABCD DEFD DDDD" is three.

But I need to count 5 words. How can count 5 words?

Comment: This because PHP is server side so it will be done first. You need to count words with javascript

Comment: function countWords(str) {
  return str.split(/\s+/).length;
}

Comment: But my intention isn't count the words.
My intention is pass the strings to php MySQL.
When $sql = "select ..........where x = '" .$cat. "';
But that $cat isn't strings, can't success to read.
How can I change the $cat  to be String?